# PHP error_log output format differs for custom log

Tags: php, format, output, error-log

PHP 7.2. When I use:

```
error_log('test');
```

in  the error log I see an entry:

```
[31-Jan-2020 20:05:28 UTC] test
```

(note the date/time in the beginning of the line)

When I use:

```
error_log('test',3, 'my_error_log');
```

I just got:

```
test
```

in the 'my_error_log' file - there is no date time at the beginning. Even new lines are not added automatically.

Why two error_log calls produce different output? How can I control it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the `error_log` probably outputs to the default log file whose location depends on the server's software which prepends your message with a datetime string.
`error_log` does not prepend strings.

> Even new lines are not added automatically.

According to the PHP docs, when you choose `message_type` with a value of 3, new lines aren't automatically added. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php